# Regex for asp.net help

Tags: asp.net, regex

I'm new to regular expressions and can't get the hang of them. Can you provide me with some help?

I need a regular expression to assign to a textbox that will allow 6 numbers followed by an A,M or G.

The following is the furthest I've got, it allows 6 numbers but that's it:

```
 ^[0-9]{6}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were close.

```
^[0-9]{6}[AMG]$
```

^:  Start of string
[0-9]{6}: match 6 numbers between 0-9, inclusive
[AMG]:  match 1 of the letters
$:  end of string

Comment: Thanks! it worked perfectly. Will set your answer to accepted answer once the 10 mins past by. What would i have to type if i wanted "AMG" as a whole string as the ending?

Comment: You would use either ^[0-9]{6}AMG$ or ^[0-9]{6}[A][M][G]$  I believe the first one would work, but you're guaranteed the second one does.

Comment: first one `^[0-9]{6}AMG$` should be fine